# Input to a seperate file (let the user write text in a python program as it writes to a file)

Tags: python, file, input, output, file-io

How do I let the user write text in my python program that will transfer into a file using open "w"?

I only figured out how write text into the seperate document using print. But how is it done if I want input to be written to a file? In short terms: Let the user itself write text to a seperate document.

Here is my code so far:

```
def main():

    print ("This program let you create your own HTML-page")

    name = input("Enter the name for your HTML-page (end it with .html): ")

    outfile = open(name, "w")

    code = input ("Enter your code here: ")

    print ("This is the only thing getting written into the file", file=outfile)

main ()
```

Comment: `outfile.write(code)` and when you are done: `outfile.close()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, use raw_input instead of input.  This way you capture the text as a string instead of trying to evaluate it.  But to answer your question:

```
with open(name, 'w') as o:
    o.write(code)
```

You can also surround that code in a loop that keeps repeating until the user hits a certain key if you would like them to be able to hit enter when typing their html file.

**EDIT:** Example of loop to allow continuous user input:

```
with open(name, 'w') as o:
    code = input("blah")
    while (code != "exit")
        o.write('{0}\n'.format(code))
        code = input("blah")
```

That way, the loop will keep running until the user types in "exit" or whatever string you choose.  The format line inserts a newline into the file.  I'm still on python2 so I'm not completely sure how input handles newlines, but if it includes it, feel free to remove the format line and use it as above.

Comment: I use input because I'm using python 3, so the raw_input doesn't work. Okey thank you very much I will try this! I have only done simple if and while-loops for user-login so not sure if I'm able to write that kind of loop, but it's certainly something I want for the program. Is there any possibility you can show me how it's done?

Comment: I've tried as you said and it didn't seem like I needed the format line. But it seems to work both ways. The problem is that the program only writes the last line I write to the document. So somehow the program doesn't "store" everything I write, only the last line.

Comment: Oops, that's my fault, see the updated version, I was continually opening the file for 'write', which clobbered all previous changes

Comment: Hmm this is wierd. I wrote it as you explained. 
The problem is after my first line of code (when i press enter), the program stucks, the next "Enter your code" doesn't show and I can't do anything.

Comment: It seems like the loop get stuck when i type the first line, and then it loops that line into the text-document. For example: I started typing <html> and pressed enter, nothing happened so I closed my terminal. When I opened the html file it was just <html> over and over againg like thousands of times.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

    print ("This program let you create your own HTML-page")

    name = input("Enter the name for your HTML-page (end it with .html): ")

    outfile = open(name),'w')

    code = input ("Enter your code here: ")

    outfile.write(code)

main ()
```

This does not accept multi line code entries. You will need an additional module for that.

Comment: This seems like an oddly specific "improvement" that wasn't asked for.  Why limit the file name to something within the users home directory?

Comment: I suppose you are right. I just do that by default any time I call a file. I never thought about not including a directory.

Comment: If you skip it, then the user could put it wherever their heart desires.  A use case in this example might be wherever the web server lives, which almost surely isn't in the home directly